# Intrusive Arrows on Windows 7 application windows

Tags: windows-7

I have this strange issue with Windows 7 application windows.

I don't know what is causing these arrows to appear, but it's mildly intrusive to my experience:

[image]

Anyone know what these are and how to disable them? they are not visible by default.

Comment: What applications are open? Use Task Manager to check. Unless you're viewing only part of a screen, due to resolution issues, the buttons would not seem to be from Windows.

Comment: Any chance you have UltraMon installed? In any case, this is coming from some program that is installed.  Have a look through your list of installed programs for an idea.

Answer (score 0):

resolved it, it was a program called "SplitScreen", didn't ever work either.